# Dynamic Excel Hyperlinks on Destination Data

Tags: excel, vba

I created an Excel document which imports a CSV file with data from AD which basically creates a phonebook, it is exported to a PDF after. However, I'm being asked to create a way to easily jump to last names based on letters.

What I'm trying to do is create hyperlinks in Excel which will survive the PDF conversion. They need to be dynamic, as the location of the last name will change daily. So the hyperlink needs to search the "Phonelist" sheet, for the first cell in column A with first letter A-Z and then hyperlink to that cell. I'm stuck and barely know where to start.

The PDF conversion is via Powershell, and the data import is via a linked CSV file which does a data refresh every time it is opened. What I could theoretically also do, is try to create a new sheet for every letter of the alphabet, but I'd rather avoid that as the data would be more segmented than we'd like.

Save as PDF

```
$workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, 'C:\users\aricci\Phonebook\Telephonebook.pdf')
```

Here's my working link right now. 2 problems, first is I need it to start the range at Cell A2, not A1 which is a header. Second, is that it does not survive the PDF conversion.

```
=HYPERLINK("#" & CELL("address",INDEX(Phonelist!A:A,MATCH("A*",Phonelist!A:A,0))),"A")
```

I would assume the VBA would be similar to this, but I'm not sure how to edit it for what I need.

```
Sub CreateHyperlinks()
Dim cl As Range

For Each cl In Range("B1:B100").Cells '## Modify as needed
    cl.Hyperlinks.Add cl, cl.Value, , , cl.Offset(0,-1).Value
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured it out...it's not pretty, I'm replicating this for each of the 26 cells, but it works. I also now need to figure out how to run Acrobat via script, but that's outside the scope of this question.

```
For Each cl In Range("A8").Cells '## Modify as needed
cl.Hyperlinks.Add cl.Offset(-1, 0), cl.Value, , , cl.Offset(-1, 0).Value
On Error Resume Next
Next
```